# move prices block to another block by layout.xml

Tags: price, magento-2.1.7, layout-update

How can I move price block in catalog category?

I tried it using this code:

`<move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.main" before="-">`

in **catalog_category_view.xml** but nothing does not changed

Comment: Can u please tell me `catalog_category_view.xml` location?

Comment: Have you make changes into your current theme "catalog_category_view.xml"

Comment: @AmitBera app/design/frontend/Sm/market/Magento_Catalog

Comment: @DhirenVasoya yeah ... i triad into both them

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to move it in the category view page, then you can't move it via layout xml.

But you can move it by editing

> /app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml

find `<?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?>` and move it whereever you want.

But if you are trying to move it on the product view page, then use:

```
<move element="product.price.final" destination="product.info.main" before="-">
```

in

> /app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

clear static files and cache afterwards to see the changes.

Comment: i use <?php echo $block->getProductPrice($_product) ?> and hidden by display none 
thanks